# Novice with Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have just downloaded Python 3.3.2 to use on windows7 and run the msi file to install. After installation I have tried using the prog only to find that every time I run my initial print 'hello world' it keeps reporting a syntax error. 
I have tried both single and double quotes but each time reports a syntax. It will add say 8 + 9 and return the answer but no joy with using a print statement.
I have tried both the shell and a new window but without success.
Any advice please much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3.x, you have to do `print('hello world')`.

In Python 2.x, `print` was a statement, like `if`, `for`, etc. Now it is a function, thus the `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using instructions for a python-2 program, where `print` was a statement, rather than a function. In python >= 3, you have to do `print(something)`, rather than just `print something`.

Comment: Since no one else seems to be interested in this question anymore, and it is the right answer, here's my +1, even though your answer was 16 seconds later than mine. :-P